# How can I use type traits to limit the universal reference parameters of a function to r-value references?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to define a function `op2()` with a universal reference parameter.

Depending on the type, I want to distinguish further, if the function parameter in `op2()` is an r-value reference of type `test`.
If this is the case, I want to define the return type of `op2` as `int`.
In all other cases, the return type should be `void`.

Here is my ME:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class test {
    public:
    test(const std::string& str) : _str(str){}
    test(test&& t) = default;
    test(const test& t) = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, test&& t) {
        os << t._str;
        return os;
    }

    private:
    std::string _str;
};

template<typename T>
void op(T&& x) {
    std::cout << " is rvalue ref? " << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << " is a test rvalue ref? " << std::is_same<test&&, decltype(x)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(x) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>        // This is A
typename std::enable_if<std::negation<std::conjunction<std::is_same<test, T>, std::is_rvalue_reference<T>>>::value>::type op2(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "op2: A: " << std::forward<T>(x) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>    // This is B
typename std::enable_if<std::conjunction<std::is_same<test, T>, std::is_rvalue_reference<T>>::value, int>::type op2(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "op2: B: " << std::move(x) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
    op(std::string{"r-value string"});
    std::string str{"l-value string"};
    op(str);
    op(test{"test"});

    op2(std::string{"r-value string"}); //gets into A
    op2(str); //gets into A
    op2(test{"r-value string"}); //Should get into B, but actually gets into A
}
```

The problem with the code is, that the last `op2()`-call gets into the wrong overload.

I have tried another function, `op()` which gets the right types via `decltype()`, but I don't know how I can use `decltype()` in the type-trait.

I am using C++17 with gcc8.2

Comment: Maybe a simple overload can do the job here, `int op2(test &&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `decltype` when you only have types, you have to use `std::declval`:

```
decltype(std::declval<T>())
```

But you will always get a rvalue reference out of it, so that's not what you want. Instead, leverage the type that gets deduced by the forwarding reference. `T` won't be a reference if you pass in an rvalue and will be a `T&` for an lvalue.

What this means is that you can modify B to:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<test, T>, int> op2(T&& x);
```

Because as said before, if you pass in an rvalue of type `test`, `T` will get deduced to just `test`.

Comment: But than I can use this functions with l-values too, this is not what I want.

Comment: Acually, the std:declval<T> is what I need:

`template<typename T>    // This is B
typename std::enable_if<std::conjunction<std::is_same<test, T>, std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(std::declval<T>())>>::value, int>::type op2(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "op2: B: " << std::move(x) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @byteunit You can't use that function with lvalues, that's the point.

Comment: but as I said, that is exactly, what I wanted, I want to use that function only by rvalues.

Comment: This was because of your modification approach.

Comment: The modification approach works. You can't call it with lvalues.

Comment: Now, I get what you acually ment. You are right, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

A forwarding reference `T&&` will never deduce its template argument `T` as an rvalue reference type. If the argument is an rvalue of type `test`, then `T` will be deduced as `test`, while if the argument is an lvalue of type `test`, then `T` will be deduced as `test&`.

The overloads should therefore be rewritten as:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<test, T>, void> op2(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "op2: A: " << std::forward<T>(x) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<test, T>, int> op2(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "op2: B: " << std::move(x) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, simple overload is simpler:

```
template<typename T>
void op2(T&& x) { // This is A
    std::cout << "op2: A: " << std::forward<T>(x) << std::endl;
}

int op2(test&& x) { // This is B
    std::cout << "op2: B: " << std::move(x) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/8W76Ko)

Comment: In this case, you are right, but as I said, I have to use universal references, since my originial problem is not exactly the minial problem.

Comment: tag dispatching might help in your more complicated case.